# In iOS How to get UICollectionView cell index with UITableView section index?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uicollectionview

Im using `UICollectionView` Inside `TableView cell`. All is done well. Now I need to set an action listener of collection view cell by following method i am getting only collection view cell index.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"The Index is: %li",(long)indexPath.row);
}
```

But i also need  `UITableview` section index with collection view cell index. Is there have any default function to get the `UITableView` Section index and Collection view Cell index.

For Better understand my question:  I have 4 section in UITable and each section have 20 UI Collection  View Cell.

Please Help me some one to overcome my problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using custom tableviewcell class?

Comment: There is no default function that will give you both these things, so far as I know. You could try setting the tag property of your collection view cell to hold the section number of the table view section it is contained in.

Comment: You can use tag value to get table section index like below
//set tag value
aCollectionViewInstaceForATableSection.tag = indexpath.section

And you can get tag from instance of collectionView
section = aCollectionViewInstaceForTableSectionOne.tag

Comment: @akhilrajtr Yes,I'm using custom tableviewcell.Can you please give me an example to set the tag value programmatically.I am new in iOS

Comment: @iOS_Binid : Your tricks help me to get my answer!Thank you so much